# Slide animate divs horizontally using jQuery

Tags: jquery, menu, navigation, slide, sliding

I would like to create a similar animation of sliding panels like this website:
http://www.grano.hu/

I have a fixed vertical side bar main navigation div on the left side of the browser with links that when clicked should slide out to the right a secondary navigation bar from behind so it appears right next to 
the main navigation bar. This secondary navigation bar would also have links that when clicked would slide out from behind to the right a final third div with content (just like in the website above).

When you click on a different link in the secondary bar the content div should slide back left so it's hidden, and be immediately followed by a different content div sliding right to replace it.

Also, if a link from the fixed main navigation bar is clicked, the current content div should slide left, followed immediately by the secondary navigation menu sliding back to the left as well so that the only panel showing is the fixed main navigation menu. A different corresponding secondary navigation panel should then immediately slide out to the right.

I am new to jQuery and don't understand how to structure this, so I would greatly appreciate your help.

Essentially, I would like my navigation panels to slide in and out just like the sample website above, but instead of having to click on the close icons in the top right of each panel to collapse the panels, I want these functions to run automatically.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions

Comment: You want to take a look at .animate() from jquery http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: This website is an even better example of what I would like to achieve: http://the-studio.co.il/